# Connect different wallets same time and make transaction

Tags: transactions, pending-transactions

actually i want to do this on bnb chain, the thing is that I have multiple wallets in the bnb chain and so I want to use a claim option and claim the token from multiple wallets, so I want to know is there any way I can claim from multiple wallets automatically using any script or something like that instead of doing it manually –

Comment: Hi Dasapan! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! Do not create the same question multiple times. If some detail is missing you can edit your own questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the contract’s addresses you want to interact with and their ABI.

Than using web3py for example you can interact with these contracts.